# Number of ways to write n as a sum of m non-negative integers each less than k

Tags: combinatorics

What is the number of m-tuples of non-negative integers, each less than k, whose sum is n ?

For example, if m=3, k=4 and n=5 then there are only 12 possibilities: (0 2 3),
(0 3 2),
(1 1 3),
(1 2 2),
(1 3 1),
(2 0 3),
(2 1 2),
(2 2 1),
(2 3 0),
(3 0 2),
(3 1 1),
(3 2 0).

Answer (score 2):

Using generating functions is one way to go!

In your example, we want the coefficient of $x^5$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+x^3)^3$. The coefficient does check out to be $12$. (I will let you check for yourself)

In general, you would want the coefficient of $x^n$ from the expansion of $(1+x+ \dots + x^{k-1} )^m$

Comment: Can you explain how and why this works?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/school/mathjams-transcripts?id=113) may be able to help explain it